# how to resolve unknownhost exception in java without root access

Tags: java, macos

I am getting `java.net.UnknownHostException` on my mac

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: EC-C02NL85VG3QD: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
    ... 129 more
```

I have got the solution by adding `127.0.0.1 EC-C02NL85VG3QD` line in `/etc/hosts` file.
The problem is I dont have root access.
So how can I resolve this error without root/sudo access ?

Adding a snippet of logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorFactory.<init>(SqlGeneratorFactory.java:40)
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.SqlGeneratorFactory.getInstance(SqlGeneratorFactory.java:54)
at liquibase.executor.AbstractExecutor.applyVisitors(AbstractExecutor.java:23)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.access$500(JdbcExecutor.java:36)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:304)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:112)
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.init(StandardLockService.java:87)
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.acquireLock(StandardLockService.java:188)
at liquibase.lockservice.StandardLockService.waitForLock(StandardLockService.java:154)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:186)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 107 more

Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.net.UnknownHostException: EC-C02NL85VG3QD: EC-C02NL85VG3QD: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator.<clinit>(LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator.java:32)
... 127 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: EC-C02NL85VG3QD: EC-C02NL85VG3QD: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475)
at liquibase.util.NetUtil.getLocalHostName(NetUtil.java:41)
at liquibase.sqlgenerator.core.LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator.<clinit>(LockDatabaseChangeLogGenerator.java:29)
... 127 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: EC-C02NL85VG3QD: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1295)
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1471)
... 129 more
```

Comment: I'm not sure who downvoted without a reason given, but I've removed my answer for the time being, as I cannot possibly make it any better without you providing some actual code snippets. Voting to close instead.